# adding glyphicon icon on each cell dosen't not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am filling up a table cell using the following jquery code

```
 $(this).parent().html('<span class=\"asset_value\">'+ comment +'</span><span id=\"save\" class=\"glyphicon pull-right\">&nbsp;</span>').css('color', 'red');
```

And then formatting formatting the save span using

```
$("#save").addClass('glyphicon-floppy-disk');
$("#save").css("color", "#009900");
```

I want that on each table cell onclick this formatting should be applied. However I notice that each time I click a table cell the text colour changes to red( due to .css('color', 'red')) but I don't get the glyphicon icon everytime. Any idea why so? and how can this be resolved? Looks like the span id=save is usable only once.

Thanks

Comment: `$("#save").addClass(' glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk');` try this

Answer (score 2):

ID should be unique in a document. Hence the ID selector will select the first ID it finds. Use a class instead and try with `.save` instead of `#save`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11970504)

Comment: This could be the error, the ID selector will select the first ID it founds because an ID is unique ... https://jsfiddle.net/0uvde0av/

Comment: Exactly this is the error. How to get over this? changing my current html $(this).parent().html('<span class=\"asset_value\">'+ comment +'</span><span id=\"save\" class=\"glyphicon pull-right\">&nbsp;</span>').css('color', 'red');

Comment: Since this is for all table cell contents  I have a function where on clicking any cell this content is loaded in cell. how can we have different id's for span elements then?

Comment: You can just delete the `id="save"` and add save class on the class list. Then just replace your # by a . (dot)

Comment: I am sorry I did not get "add save class on the class list. " Do you have any sample which uses this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108793/discussion-between-lovesoftlayeraj-and-dupuis-david).

Answer (score 0):

You cant try like that.

```
$("#save").addClass('glyphicon');    
$("#save").addClass('glyphicon-floppy-disk');
$("#save").css("color", "#009900");
```